# mod_rewrite vs files vs virtual subdirectories

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I have a site with virtual subdirectories (for languages) created by the means of mod_rewrite.
They work fine.
Now I need to upload some files that should be accessed via certain subdirectories only.

Currently I can access any files via any subdirectories.

```
site.com/file.txt
site.com/jp/file.txt
site.com/es/file.txt

site.com/another_file.txt
site.com/jp/another_file.txt
site.com/es/another_file.txt

site.com/third_file.txt
site.com/jp/third_file.txt
site.com/es/third_file.txt
```

I need to access these files via the related subdirectories only, if I try to access them via unrelated directory, it should throw the 404 error.

```
site.com/file.txt - for english (the only language that does not have a subdirectory)
site.com/jp/anoter_file.txt - for japaneese
site.com/es/third_file.txt - for Spanish.
```

Please note that there is no pattern in file names and there are many languages.
So, it is necessary to create separate rules for each file/subdirectory.

As there are many languages and files, it could be a nightmare to write rules for each language like this:

e.g. I want file another_file.txt to be displayed inside the jp directory only. 
So, I have to exclude it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^de/another_file.txt - [R=404]
RewriteRule ^fr/another_file.txt - [R=404]
RewriteRule ^es/another_file.txt - [R=404]
```

But I think there is a more elegant solution.
As far as I understand, this could be achieved by the means of exception.

Like this:

```
RewriteRule ! ^jp/another_file.txt - [R=404] - but it does not work.
```

Could you please assist me and let me know how to fix this expression/create a new one.?

Comment: Use a negative lookahead? That is, `^(?!jp)../another_file.txt`?

Comment: Thank you so much. This seems to be a right direction. This works for subdirectories. However, I'm still able to access files without a subdirectory. So, now it works as site.com/another_file.txt and site.com/jp/another_file.txt. The other directories throw the 404 error as expected.